# qt qmake extra compilers with dependencies among generated files

Tags: qt, code-generation, dependencies, qmake

Can qmake handle dependencies of generated source files?

We have a prf file like this:

```
idl_h.name = Generate .H file for ${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.idl
idl_h.input = IDLS  # variable containing our input files
idl_h.variable_out = HEADERS
idl_h.commands = <command that takes .idl and genrates .h>
idl_h.output = $$IDL_GEN_DIR/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.h
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += idl_h
```

This generation works fine and creates .h files at make time. The problem is that the input files (`$$IDLS`) depend on each other, and are not always built in the correct order. We have something like `app.idl`, containing:

```
#include "common.idl"
```

---

It seems the following should work

```
idl_h.depend_command = g++ -EE ... $$IDL_GEN_DIR/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.h
```

but apparently the depend_command [is not actually executed](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-13366).

---

Another idea would be to parse the dependencies out of the original idl:

```
idl_h.depends = $$system(cat ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} | grep "^#include" | sed -re 's/#include\s+["<]([^.]+)\.idl[">]/\1.h/')
```

but it seems my qmake syntax is failing me.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
idl_h.dependency_type = TYPE_C
```

to your prf, and drop the .depend_command and .depends